# How to Stop Dreamweaver 5.5 from creating .tmp files

Tags: dreamweaver

> *setup*
>
> - Using Dreamweaver CS 5.5 / Windows 7
> - I have turned off 'Preview [in browser] using temporary files'

I am noticing however every css and js file, as well as some html and php files, have temporary (.tmp) file(s) being created for them. 
These files are also being displayed in my Files window, as well as being put when I synchronize the local and remote sites.

How can I stop these tmp files from being created? or if that is not possible how can I hide them and not have them sync to the remote server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*For anyone else who runs into this.*

> Disable Design Notes from Manage Sites > Advanced Options

Comment: I have this option disabled, but occasionally Dreamweaver still creates a copy of an open file with `.tmp` extension. For `example.php`, `example.php~RFf69ae0a.TMP` in the same directory. This happens on save. It does not happen every time, seems random. Anybody knows how to solve this?